# How come the following code prints Success(4) if i'm throwing an exception inside?

Tags: scala

```
object MyRealMainObj extends App {

  println(
    Try(1)
      .map(doOne)
      .map(doTwo)

  )

  def doOne(i: Int): Int = i + 1; throw new RuntimeException("failed in one")
  def doTwo(i: Int): Int = i + 2
}
```

result:

```
Success(4)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: failed in one
    at MyRealMainObj$.delayedEndpoint$MyRealMainObj$1(TestMainArgs.scala:16)
    at MyRealMainObj$delayedInit$body.apply(TestMainArgs.scala:7)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
```

How come it printed `Success(4)` didn't the `doOne` was supposed to fail as i'm throwing exception there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wrap the code inside curly braces like,

```
def doOne(i: Int): Int = {i + 1; throw new RuntimeException("failed in one")}
```

The throw new RuntimeException("failed in one") is not within the function it is a separate line inside main flow.